# Is there a way to get all elements with a :hover class in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, hover

I have a problem that needs me to find all elements with a :hover class. Is there a way to do this. I was expecting to be able to do `$(':hover'), but strangely that doesn't seem to work.

What I wanted to be able to do was.

```
$('*:hover').mouseover(myFunction).mouseout(myFunction);
```

Comment: [This article](http://www.roslindesign.com/2011/05/04/detecting-the-hover-css-selector-style-in-jqueryjavascript/) may be of interest.

Comment: Doesn't help you much, but I'm pretty sure that `:` is not a valid character for a class.

Comment: Assuming you mean a pseudo class, this is not really possible, and you should **strongly** consider another approach to the problem. There is a workaround, to read all styles, both inline and stylesheets, parse those styles and figure out what elements match etc. and it's even harder than it sounds.

Comment: What are you trying to achive?

Answer (score 1):

This will grep by class name `:hover`

```
$.grep($('*'), function(fn) { return $(fn).hasClass(':hover') })
```

Comment: Nice idea, but doing $.grep($('*'), function(fn) { return $(fn).hasClass(':hover') }).mouseover(myFunc).mouseout(myFunc); does not seem to work.

Comment: Because `mouseover`: **Bind an event handler to the "mouseover" JavaScript event, or trigger that event on an element.** Does not operate on an array.

Comment: Good point and so Tried putting $.each around it. However, I found it only returns the elements that are currently hovered, not the list of elements that have a hover class. I guess the parse the CSS is the only approach, but not keen on that overhead.